# Bookmarking page to load specific Frame content, is there a FF add-on or somethign I can do with a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet, frame, bookmarks

I am using an application which has a cumbersome menu structure and I would like to create a bookmark to a specific page within the application.  The app does not update the url as you click around each screen, and the top level source is

I can get the url to the menu item I need, but if I use that in my bookmark, the toolbar is not loaded.

Does anyone know if there is a way I can create a bookmark where I can load the tookbar, but change the body to load a specific url?

Answer (score 0):

[iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863), a Firefox extension could allow to you script the menu navigation to where you want. You can bookmark individual macros. This isn't as elegant or simple as a simple bookmark, but it should work.

Record the actions you need done, and then play them back.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863

Comment: Thanks for the iMacros link.  Tried it, but this won't work because the steps are not always the same.  For example, depending on whether you have an authenticated session (recently logged in).  A "real" bookmark would take care of redirection, etc.

Comment: I know there's a way to do more sophisticated scripting (checking for a session, etc), but it's a challenge and I'm not sure of the best way to approach it. There just might not be a good way to do this.